# Lookup failing through REST

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS with EJB. I am trying to inject an EntityManager, but it fails with `NullPointerException`.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dummy-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/dummy</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dummy"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is the Bean:

```
@Stateless(name = "greetingBean", mappedName = "greeting")
@Path("/greeting-service")
@Remote(GreetingService.class)
public class GreetingBean implements GreetingService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public Greeting greet() {

        return new Greeting(new Random().nextInt(),
            "Minions ipsum jeje hahaha poulet tikka masala tatata bala tu. Po kass tatata bala tu poopayee la bodaaa tatata bala tu underweaaar hahaha.");

    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public void probe(Greeting greeting) {
        em.persist(new Item()); // GreetingBean.java:45
    }

}
```

I am copying the stack trace following:

"Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:module/GreetingBean"

```
Warning:   An instance of EJB class, hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.services.GreetingBean, could not be looked up using simple form name. Attempting to look up using the fully-qualified form name.
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:module/GreetingBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:module/GreetingBean]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider.lookupSimpleForm(EjbComponentProvider.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider.lookup(EjbComponentProvider.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider.access$000(EjbComponentProvider.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider$EjbFactory.provide(EjbComponentProvider.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:96)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:69)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2204)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:579)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:module/GreetingBean
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:741)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 63 more

Severe:   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:module/GreetingBean!hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.services.GreetingBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:module/GreetingBean!hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.services.GreetingBean]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider.lookupFullyQualifiedForm(EjbComponentProvider.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider.lookup(EjbComponentProvider.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider.access$000(EjbComponentProvider.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider$EjbFactory.provide(EjbComponentProvider.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:96)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:69)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2204)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:579)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:module/GreetingBean!hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.services.GreetingBean
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:741)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 63 more

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.RestApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.RestApplication threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hu.igergo.java.dummy.ejb.services.GreetingBean.probe(GreetingBean.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider$2.invoke(EjbComponentProvider.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using:

- NetBeans 8.1
- EclipseLink 2.5.2
- Java EE 7.0
- GlassFish 4.0

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I am trying it via single client, it is working well.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();

GreetingService bean = (GreetingService) ctx.lookup(
        // "java:global/dummy-backend-ear/dummy-backend-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/greetingBean"
        // "java:global/dummy-backend-ear/dummy-backend-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/greetingBean!hu.igergo.java.dummy.interfaces.services.GreetingService"
        "greeting"
        // "greeting#hu.igergo.java.dummy.interfaces.services.GreetingService"
    );
ctx.close();

bean.probe(new Greeting());
```

Comment: You will want to turn on logging to see why your persistence unit isn't being injected, but the definition seems off - you have specified transaction-type="JTA" but are passing in JDBC properties.  JTA requires a transaction manager and JTA datasource not direct JDBC connections.

Comment: And check if your `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` class is present in your deploy (check logs for any errors/warnings related to the database connection initialization).

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I edited my post and I also think everything is ok with the provider. (Because if I am trying through from a client, it persist an item well.)

Comment: @Chris Ok, I will try it, I'll be in touch with the result!

Comment: Of course, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This namespace `java:module` as emitted by the exception stack-trace is only used to refer to local enterprise beans within the same module. You decorated the bean with `@Remote`. What is the need of a remote session bean along with REST? If it is the case, then why don't you simply make the REST clients avail of that remote session bean directly avoiding the whole REST service itself? They should be "either...or".

Comment: @Tiny I need to a remote bean along with REST. Because the back-end will have two variants of client, one will require the bean (from a console app), another client will using REST api. [JAX-RS works with Enterprise JavaBeans technology.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm#GKNCY)

Comment: No. It is not true (nothing like remote EJBs is mentioned in that link either). Remote EJBs or REST may be determined by many choices. Using both of them together is not required. That "*another client*" along with the "*console app*" both can simply consume the single remote EJB in question. If it is a real remote EJB, then there is no need to think of REST or if it is a RESTful service, then there is no need to think of remote EJBs (both have their own pros and cons but it is a different story).

Comment: @ [Tiny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1391249/tiny) I think what he is trying to say is that he wants his business code to be exposed at the same time through IIOP (remote EJB for stub based clients) and REST based clients (maybe developed in a no java lib). @  [Gergo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5568480/gerg%c5%91-iv%c3%a1n) as Tiny already suggested, and if the above requirement is correct you can have both with only 1 implementation, the remote EJB . You JAXRS resource can lookup/use the remote EJB and in this  case, the application server will be smart enough to make a local call

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I solved it, like @ Tiny said. And thank you to @ javapapo also, I want exactly what you wrote! (REST based client will be an android application...) How can I accept @Tiny's answer?